# "new document or drag files here" not visible - Custom Page Layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-masterpage, custom-field-types

I have an interesting situation in that I have created a Custom Page Layout via Design Manager that I want for the home page for all Team Sites (Publishing Features have been enabled). Added a Web Part Zone Snippet to the page. All works well.

When I go to add an app part to that custom page, let's say for the Document Library the "new document or drag files here" does not appear? Is there any way to make that appear?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

It turns out to be the `ToolbarType` that was selected on the app part.

Note to self and anyone else for that matter: Select the Summary Toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution was to change the View Style from Basic Table to Default.